# Type hint for a list of possible values

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function which can take a fixed list of values: e.g.

```
def func(mode="a"):
   if mode not in ["a", "b"]:
      raise AttributeError("not ok")
```

is there a way to type hint it can only be one of these two values?

Comment: Use an enum instead of a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes,  but thats a lot of ceremony for this use case :) I have a nagging feeling that it should now be possible but I do not recall how

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you want a [literal type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
def func(mode = "a": Literal["a", "b"]):
    if mode not in ["a", "b"]:
        raise AttributeError("not ok")
```

This was introduced in Python 3.8, via [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, my google fu found anything else but not that!

Comment: Just a note that this requires the following import: `from typing_extensions import Literal`

Comment: @MaiKar that depends on the version of Python you're using - `from typing_extensions` if you need the backport for 3.5-3.7, `from typing` in the standard library for 3.8 and up. There's also a `from typing` from PyPI, not sure how much that supports.

Comment: I have a list: `my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]`, and I want to use this list both as a value and a literal type. However, Literal complains when I do `Literal[my_list]`. Do you know how I can have a Literal of a predefined list?

Comment: @Nihir see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64522040/3001761

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please help explain why to use AttributionError instead of ValueError here?

Comment: @TalGalili that was just following what the OP used, throw whichever error makes most sense for your specific case.