# Python typing from List of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

How to do python typing for list of classes.

Suppose I have following classes.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    name: str

@dataclass
class B:
   age: int

#...
CLASSES = [A, B]  #... more classes in list
```

Now I define a function that instantiate any one of the following class

```
def func(resource: Union[*CLASSES], value: Union[str, int]):
    return resource(value)
```

But type-hinting is not valid here. **How to do type hinting from List?**

Comment: Incase the possibility are 10 or more classes. There would be a lot of code for typing; making code look dirty. Besides this makes me **change only at one list** instead of **changing on every function signature** if I add new class. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "type casting", exactly? Please be specific. Note, "type casting" is not really a term that is applicable to python, although it is used informall to mean "type conversion".

Comment: If you have 10 or more possibly classes, there's already something seriously wrong with your code - it's likely they share a super-class that would be a better match; at any rate, you can't use expansion on a *variable* to get at the types that are stored in it to define the type of function parameters - you're mixing runtime and compile-time information

Comment: Type hints must be static so that the linters can validate them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for mentioning type casting. I'll correct it

Comment: @Grismar I was just considering for a scenario. Don't worry my code isn't that poor. I was just wondering how to do it :D

Comment: @Selcuk So in that case I must go with `def func(resource: [A, B, C,...])`. Because I know in runtime these hinting doesn't make any value. or does it?

Comment: No, type hints are only for the IDE/linter to make it easier to spot bugs. They are not used by the interpreter (at least not by CPython). You don't have to use a `Union`; you can use what @Grismar suggested in their answer. Unions are only necessary if you are using built-in or third party classes that you can't modify.

Comment: Do you actually need ``CLASSES`` to be a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: Dynamically Create Literal Alias from List of Valid Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/python-typing-dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, They can be any iterables.

Comment: In that case, does the suggested duplicate answerr your question?

Answer (score 2):

This achieves what you want using a super-class that all the intended classes share:

```
from typing import Union
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyDataMixin:
    pass


@dataclass
class A(MyDataMixin):
    name: str


@dataclass
class B(MyDataMixin):
    age: int


def func(resource: MyDataMixin, value: Union[str, int]):
    return resource
```

You can't use expansion in the type definition of the parameter like you were trying to do, that only works on variables at runtime.

As @Selcuk indicated in the comments, naming it `MyDataMixin` makes more sense, as the class is not intended to be used by itself. You could go further and ensure it's just an abstract class - but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Better name it a `Mixin` so that other (actual) superclasses can be extended if needed.

Comment: Shall I use **ABC** instead of *dataclass* as Parent?

Comment: Yeah, the mixin doesn't have to be a dataclass itself, although it certainly can be. I wouldn't go the route of using `ABC` unless you have specific reasons to want to use an abstract base class, like requiring an abstract method to be implemented on each subclass - but that goes way beyond what you were asking. Just inheriting from a shared base class is enough. Everything else is a different matter.