# Generate Literal in Runtime

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting, python-typing, pydantic

I want to create a `pydantic` Model with a `Literal` field, but the options should be derived from a list. Something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

opts=['foo','bar']

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    select_one : Literal[opts]
```

Is there some way this could be solved by enumeration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: Dynamically Create Literal Alias from List of Valid Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/python-typing-dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order for this to work, the `Literal` needs to be over a `tuple` (see also [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#literal-type)).

There are several options, depending on your situation:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

# First option:
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    select_one: Literal['foo', 'bar']

# Second option:
opts_tuple = ('foo', 'bar')
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    select_one: Literal[opts_tuple]

# Third option:
opts_list = ['foo', 'bar']
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    select_one: Literal[tuple(opts_list)]
```

Comment: From the mypy documentation: "`Literal` types may contain one or more literal bools, ints, strs, bytes, and enum values. However, literal types cannot contain arbitrary expressions: types like `Literal[my_string.trim()]`, `Literal[x > 3]`, or `Literal[3j + 4]` are all illegal." As such, while all your options are valid *python* syntax, it is only your first option that would mean anything to a type-checker (and meaning something to the type checker is the whole point of adding type hints). https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#limitations

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't aware of the `mypy` limitations. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.  If you mix in `str` with `enum.Enum`, you'll get an enumeration with members that are fully backwards-compatible with strings (can be used anywhere a `str` type is expected) and are type-checker friendly.

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Options(str, Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    select_one : Options
```