# How to create typing.Literal from multiple lists of values in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have two lists. I want to create a `Literal` using both these lists

```python
category1 = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
category2 = ["application/pdf"]

SUPPORTED_TYPES = typing.Literal[category1 + category2]
```

Is there any way to do this?

I have seen the question [typing: Dynamically Create Literal Alias from List of Valid Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/typing-dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values) but this doesnt work for my use case because I dont want `mimetype` to be of type `typing.Tuple`.

I will be using the `Literal` in a function -

```python
def process_file(filename: str, mimetype: SUPPORTED_TYPES)
```

What I have tried -

```python
supported_types_list = category1 + category2
SUPPORTED_TYPES = Literal[supported_types_list]
SUPPORTED_TYPES = Literal[*supported_types_list]

# this gives 2 different literals, rather i want only 1 literal
SUPPORTED_TYPES = Union[Literal["image/jpeg", "image/png"], Literal["application/pdf"]]
```

Comment: "because I dont want mimetype to be of type typing.Tuple" - but it wouldn't be of type `typing.Tuple`. It'd be a literal type, exactly what you need.

Comment: Maybe you just got confused by the fact that the all caps are the other way around in the question you linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the same technique as in the question you linked: build the lists from the literal types, instead of the other way around:

```
SUPPORTED_IMAGE_TYPES = typing.Literal["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
SUPPORTED_OTHER_TYPES = typing.Literal["application/pdf"]

SUPPORTED_TYPES = typing.Literal[SUPPORTED_IMAGE_TYPES, SUPPORTED_OTHER_TYPES]

category1 = list(typing.get_args(SUPPORTED_IMAGE_TYPES))
category2 = list(typing.get_args(SUPPORTED_OTHER_TYPES))
```

The only part of this that wasn't already covered in the other answer is `SUPPORTED_TYPES = typing.Literal[SUPPORTED_IMAGE_TYPES, SUPPORTED_OTHER_TYPES]`, which, [yeah, you can do that](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time). It's equivalent to your original definition of `SUPPORTED_TYPES`.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to this -
Create a literal for both the lists, and then create a combined literal

```python
category1 = Literal["image/jpeg", "image/png"]
category2 = Literal["application/pdf"]

SUPPORTED_TYPES = Literal[category1, category2]
```

Sorry: hadnt seen that monica answered the question