# Pylance Generic class type cannot be assigned from typing.get_args()

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I have a `Literal` type of particular string values.
I'm trying to generate a list of those strings as well dynamically:

```py
from typing import List, Literal, get_args

Color = Literal['red', 'green', 'blue']

colors = List[Color] = get_args(Color)
```

The third line at `List` is throwing this error:

```
Generic class type cannot be assigned    Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I'm attempting to replicate this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522240/12574341

Comment: The equivalent of what the other answer shows is `colors: List[Color] = get_args(Color)`. Note the colon.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a colon instead of an equal sign. If you want to make it a list, a type cast is required to cast from `tuple[Any, ...]` to `list[Color]`.

```py
from typing import cast, Literal, get_args


Color = Literal["red", "green", "blue"]

colors = cast(list[Color], list(get_args(Color)))
```