# DRF: Dynamic literal type hint for models.TextChoices

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, enums

Given this model

```py
from django.db import models

class Olympian(models.Model):
    MedalType = models.TextChoices('MedalType', 'GOLD SILVER BRONZE')
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=MedalType.choices, default=MedalType.GOLD)
```

and this function which takes in the `CharField` as a param

```py
fn_with_type_hint(olympian.medal)
```

How can I type hint the param more strictly without hard-coding like this?

```py
def fn_with_type_hint(medal: Literal['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']):
    pass
```

---

#### What I tried

I tried `Olympian.medal` but it's just a string

```py
medal: Olympian.medal
```

I also tried variations of this to no avail

```py
medal: Literal[*Olympian.MedalType.values]
```

I also can't use this solution because I don't start with a list of strings

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522240/8479344