# Type Validation Based on the Contents of a JSON file

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-hinting

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/typing-dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values) question, except here the valid arguments are contained in a json file.

In Python using VSCode, I'd like to define a type which is based on the contents of a JSON file. Is such a thing possible?

For example,

`data.json` contains data for three object: `an_option`, `another_option`, and `yet_another_option`.

```
{
   "data": [
        {
            "id":"an_option",
            "property":"value"
        },
        {
            "id":"another_option",
            "property":"value"
        },
        {
            "id":"yet_another_option",
            "property":"value"
        }
    ]
}
```

In `main.py`, I have defined a type that allows Intellisence to suggest these options when writing data of that type. Intellisense suggests my options as parameters when calling `test_function`.

```
from typing import Literal


MyType = Literal[
    "an_option",
    "another_option",
    "yet_another_option"
]

def test_function(option_chosen: MyType):
    print(option_chosen)
    pass

test_function("an_option")
```

However, then the names for my options must be replicated in multiple files, which seems cumbersome. I would like the `MyType` type to update when I add entries to the `data` list from `data.json`. For example, something like

```
from typing import Literal
import json 
file = open('data.json', 'r')
data = json.load(file)
list_of_options_with_properties = data["data"]
option_name_list = list()
for option in  list_of_options_with_properties:
    option_name_list.append(option["id"])
MyType = Literal[tuple(option_name_list)]
def test_function(option_chosen: MyType):
    print(option_chosen)
    pass

test_function("an_option")
```

Unfortunately, this does not help autocomplete becuase `option_name_list` is not defined until runtime. Is it possible to have Intellisense to read the contents of the json file to define a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly with Python's type system, this isn't feasible due to the nature of static type checkers operating before code execution. However, you can craft a solution using a code generation tool. You could write a script that reads your JSON file and automatically updates a module with the relevant `Literal` type.

```py
# codegen.py
import json
from typing import List

def generate_literal_type_from_json(filename: str) -> List[str]:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    options = [item["id"] for item in data["data"]]
    return options

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = generate_literal_type_from_json("data.json")
    with open("generated_types.py", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"from typing import Literal\n\n")
        f.write(f"MyType = Literal{tuple(options)}\n")
```

Run this script, and it will produce a `generated_types.py` file. You can then use the `MyType` type in your main code from this generated file.