# Python - Passing enum set to Literal

Tags: python, enums, python-typing, literals, pyright

I have a question about this construct:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal

class Fruit(Enum):
    Apple = "apple"
    Bannana = "bananna"
    Watermelon = "watermelon"

top_fruits = {
    Fruit.Watermelon,
    Fruit.Bannana
}

top_fruits_literal = Literal[*top_fruits]
```

VSCode is highlighting `*top_fruits` as `"Unpacked arguments cannot be used in type argument lists"`,
but the code works just fine.

What am I missing, is it bad idea creating Literal like this? Is there anything to change to do it "right way"?

Comment: You can't go this way. You have two options, either repeat twice or go other way around: `YourType = Literal[Fruit.Watermelon, Fruit.Banana]`, then `top_fruits = set(typing.get_args(YourType))`. Please note that types should be CamelCase as classes in python - this allows to better differentiate them from regular variables. Your Literal should be called `TopFruitsLiteral` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typing: Dynamically Create Literal Alias from List of Valid Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/typing-dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values)

Comment: "the code works just fine." because it doesn't really do anything

Answer (score 0):

It works because the Python interpreter can run that code just fine. The Python interpreter doesn't do type checking though.

However, type checkers aren't Python interpreters, and they're not smart enough to run it - which is what VSCode is saying.

Comment: So is it good idea to use it or not? And can I prevent somehow the checker to highlight that or should I leave it like it is?

Comment: It's not a good idea, since the type checker doesn't understand it.

Comment: so it is better to "duplicate" the code and write `top_fruits_literal = Literal[Fruit.Watermelon, Fruit.Bannana, Fruit.Kiwi]` ? (Duplicate, because I also need the `top_fruits` for another purpose..)

Comment: `Literal[Fruit.Watermelon, Fruit.Bannana, Fruit.Kiwi]` is redundant with `Fruit` itself, why does it exist?

Answer (score -4):

You actually do not need to give `*` for a list,

```
top_frutis_literal = Literal[top_fruits]
```

This is good enough and that is why you are getting that error in Visual Studio. Although there is no error from Python.

Comment: "*This is good enough*": Except for that `top_fruits` [is not a valid type argument](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBApgdgV2gSwgBzCALlAooiAWAChRIosBPNZOAcylQ2ygBlksYQBDAGxJIBjXtwDOoqADEQCDgAp8SAJQAuElA1QAgmjS8YUALxQARN136T6zQCFucOPe5HTAIycPuV4pqgB1bk4QCBheMDgXEwB3QK4QsLhvEiwwNAB9UFksCWMAb2sNaSyAOgCg%2BPCAGgKpGQ5iu09HEgBfAWIU9MyOUTTeDi4%2BF3YgvgBtToy67IBdEiA) for `Literal`.

Comment: This is giving me: "Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value"

Comment: This answer is a nonsense, such construction does not define a Literal type.