Unable to use starred expression with Literal
I am working on a project and am trying to unpack a list so that I can make it a Literal for Pydantic library. But the code is throwing this error, Python version 3.10 does not support starred expressions in subscriptions.
Here is the code causing the error,
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

members = ["Member1", "Member2"]
options = ["FINISH"] + members

class routeResponse(BaseModel):
    next: Literal[*options] # <- this line is throwing error

The code is working just fine if I remove the Literal i.e., [*options] is working perfectly fine. So, the problem in using * and Literal together. Does anyone know what might be causing the error?
I am currently using python version 3.10.9.

This feature was added in 3.11.

Why are you using Python 3.10 if you want this feature? What's keeping you on 3.10? The cause is clear, as both Python and user Barmar are telling you.  A solution would be to upgrade Python or literally spell it out like Union[Literal["FINISH"], Literal["Member1"], Literal["Member2"]]

Without Literal, [*options] is an ordinary list display. I don't think any version of Python lets you define a Literal type like this. (You can unpack a TypeVarTuple, not an arbitrary iterable value.)

As a side note, try for examples that don't include optional modules like pydantic. Your example would have had the same error with a class that does not inherit. As stands, a person needs pydantic to test, limiting quality responses.

Since 3.11 such assignment is syntactically valid - starred unpacking can now be used like this, and can't be used prior to 3.11. However, since you tagged this [tag:python-typing], I think it's important to spell out: this won't be supported by any typechecker. If you want this for static typing, go other way around, and here's a dupe for that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522040/dynamically-create-literal-alias-from-list-of-valid-values

Okays, so after a few more tries and checking different options from here and there I got the correct answer.
Thanks to @kuza for mentioning that Literal accepts a tuple of types or literals here.
After reading this response, I tried Literal[(*options,)] and now it is working as expected. Here is the full code just in case required.
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Literal

members = ["Member1", "Member2"]
options = ["FINISH"] + members

class routeResponse(BaseModel):
    next: Literal[(*options,)]

